# Right clicking bookmarks in firefox in osx doesn't work

Tags: mac, firefox, mouse

I have a macbook pro 13" that I got just last week and iv noticed that I can't rightclick bookmarks in the bookmarks toolbar or the bookmarks menu. 
Doing so in the bookmarks organizer works just fine and the same goes for every other app on my system.

After googling around this seems to be a common problem ([mozilla support post](http://support.mozilla.com/tiki-view_forum_thread.php?comments_offset=0&comments_threadId=0&comments_parentId=7607&comments_threshold=0&thread_sort_mode=commentDate_asc&forumId=1&time_control=3600)) but I suspect that there is some fix or workaround out there, I just can't find it.

How do I solve this?

Edit: Just realised that it works for single bookmarks in the toolbar menu but not when bookmarks are in folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think this works in Mac OS X for Mozilla based (Gecko/XUL) browsers.

See [bug 300710](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=300710). This has been around for some time, I think I remember confirming this myself when I worked on Netscape 7, Mozilla/Seamonkey.

(I was on the QA team for some of those releases).

In Camino and Safari, the right click on a menu-of-toolbar-bookmarks gets mapped to a mouseclick.

Comment: As an alternative you can try the **Bookmarks Sidebar** by going to View->Sidebar->Bookmarks or **CMD + B** . It has context menus for folders!

Answer (score 0):

What functionality are you trying to get from the context menu of your foldered bookmarks? If you're trying to open in a new tab, hold down CMD when clicking. If you'd like to open in a new window, hold SHIFT.

While not an ideal solution as its two steps, you can drag a foldered bookmark to the toolbar and then right click it there to get the context menu.

And less ideal, but possibly useful, is look into an online bookmark service such as [delicious](http://delicious.com), and then all your bookmarks are available on any OS :-).

Comment: I want to delete the bookmarks without having to move them down to the toolbar where I can get access to the rightclickmenu.

Comment: Does one have to enable some setting to be able to make use of the CMD or SHIFT while clicking on a bookmark from the bookmarks menu? It does not work for me. CMD + click does work when clicking on links on pages and stuff, but not on the bookmarks. -1 for not answering the question and beating around the bush (Especially with the second suggestion).

Comment: Please note why this wasn't useful in the downvote, the question didn't say "how do I delete bookmarks from the toolbar context menu". The two-step method *does* solve the issue of deleting w/o opening the manager/organizer.